# Split variable on every other row to form two new columns in data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

After scraping a pdf, I have a data frame with a chr text var:

```
df = data.frame(text = c("abc","def","abc","def"))
```

My question is how to turn it into:

```
df = data.frame(text1 = c("abc","abc"),text2=c("def","def"))
```

I am able to index the rows and manually rebuild a new df, but was curious if it could be done within the `dplyr` pipe.

All solutions I have been able to find involve splitting each row, but not to split whole rows of a variable into new columns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you could create a new column (`ind`) for grouping which would have same values every alternate rows and then we `group_by` `ind` and create a sequence column (`id`) to `spread` the data into two columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(ind = rep(c(1, 2),length.out = n())) %>%
  group_by(ind) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  spread(ind, text) %>%
  select(-id)


#   `1`   `2`  
#  <fct> <fct>
#1 abc   def  
#2 abc   def
```

---

A base R option would be to `split` `df` into separate dataframe every alternate rows creating a sequence using `rep` and `cbind` them together to form 2-column data frame.

```
do.call("cbind", split(df, rep(c(1, 2), length.out = nrow(df))))

#  text text
#1  abc  def
#3  abc  def
```

Comment: Thank you, went with the dplyr option though not sure if it might have been worth it to break the chain to use your base solution. Didn't understand how to work split, so now I get it. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

We could do this in `base R`.  Use the `matrix` route to rearrange a vector/column into a `matrix` and then convert it to `data.frame` (`as.data.frame`).  As the number of columns is constant i.e. 2, specify that value in `ncol`

```
as.data.frame(matrix(df$text, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, 
      dimnames = list(NULL, c('text1', 'text2'))))
#   text1 text2
#1   abc   def
#2   abc   def
```

---

Or another option is `unstack` from `base R` after creating a sequence of alternate ids (making use of the recycling)

```
unstack(transform(df, val = paste0('text', 1:2)), text ~ val)
#    text1 text2
#1   abc   def
#2   abc   def
```

---

Or we can `split` into a `list` of `vector`s and then `cbind` it together

```
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, split(as.character(df$text), 1:2)))
#   1   2
#1 abc def
#2 abc def
```

---

Or another option is `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), rowid(text)~ text)[, text := NULL][]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("abc","def","abc","def"))
```

Comment: Nice to see the `do.call` answer. Tried it myself(earlier) and got funny results. What does the `1:2` do?

Comment: @NelsonGon Thanks.  When we use 1:2 on a column that have length greater than 2, it gets recycled as `1 2 1 2 ...` and split based on that group.  You can explicitly specify with `rep` though.  It is a nice feature.  Here, the OP mentioned splitting by alternate rows.  This can be any value BTW.  i.e. `TRUE/FALSE` or `'A', 'B'`

Comment: Thank you, my data was small enough for dplyr, but good to know the data.table solution as well.